# Check if model has field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

my code

```
 var bvcD = _db.BVCData.GetBVCDataByMetric(metric);
 // this one is simple "Select * from table"
```

which gets a list of recordrs from DB.

I can loop through the data with foreach loop

```
foreach (var item in bvcD)
{
    // How can I check if "item" has column/key "report" ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this :

```
foreach (var item in bvcD)
{
    Type t = item.GetType();
    var props = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        string columnName = p.ToString();
        // Column name with type prepended
        // I get column name by doing columnName.Replace("Double ", "");
        // "Double" is the column dataType here
    }
}
```

This seems an ugly way for retrieving column names.
Let me know if you have any other way to do it.